# Ryzen3 3200G VEGA8 low gpu performance - bad driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-ryzen

Please help to solve my problem with APU graphics performance. Ubuntu 19.10 is freshly installed using defaults on a new PC with the Ryzen3 3200G APU with VEGA 8 graphics.

The driver looks loaded properly but performance is very low, as if there was no hardware acceleration; glxgears runs at 30-50 FPS !

```
root@HTPC:/home/htpc# vainfo
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 1.5.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_5
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.5 (libva 2.5.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Mesa Gallium driver 19.2.1 for AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.33.0, 5.3.0-18-generic, LLVM 9.0.0)
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

and

```
root@HTPC:/home/htpc# lsmod | grep amdgpu
amdgpu               4190208  17
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdgpu
gpu_sched              32768  1 amdgpu
ttm                   106496  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 amdgpu
drm                   491520  8 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,ttm
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 saa716x_tbs_dvb,amdgpu
```

Everything looks like Ubuntu detected the hardware properly and loaded good drivers, but why is it slower than my old PC with an i3-4130? :(

How may I troubleshoot this for improved graphics performance?

Comment: amd 3200g is Q2 2019 relased, so i think better support should have newest realase than oldest

Comment: See https://community.amd.com/thread/228794 and look for the 11/8/18 post by qnerd.

Comment: its something different, i dont have issues with start system or install, i have only low performance, now tested unigine heaven benchmark, and i have result with almost 3FPS in 3D!!!!, but i dont have any errors with drivers, beacasue ot this i dont know where is the problem. maybe on linux i dont get better performance with this APU, but i dont belive it, it mus be working much better, but how to set this ;(

Answer (score 2):

I recently bought a Ryzen 3200G and a Gigabyte B450M-DS3H with 16GB running Ubuntu 19.10.

The graphics are failing to draw the screen specially on web browsers, needing repeatedly refreshing or changing screen. Also, I had my system freezing completely I had to reset from time to time.

The ugly truth is AMD is not supporting Vega 8 embedded GPU for Linux and the Ryzen Zen will need more time to iron out all driver related issues.

But nobody is telling this out loud. Phoronix.com tested both 3200G and 3400G and didn't mention any issues. I had to discover the hard way.

So, my solution so far is:

1. Install Oibaff GPU drivers:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
   sudo apt update
   ```

   Then upgrade or dist-upgrade. Some say dist-upgrade is a better and thorough upgrade.
2. After disabled IOMMU on BIOS, the GPU issues stopped and it appears to have an overall performance improvement.

My cheap MB doesn't have SVM, but you could try to disabled it on BIOS to see if something improves.

That is it.

Comment: Have you tried [the customized kernel](https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries) for Raven Ridge? I realize that your APU is Picasso, but I believe the Vega GPU side is essentially unchanged, so it might help you. I am considering buying a Picasso myself, so I'd be very interested to know whether it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208271/artifacts-with-amd-ryzen-5-3400g-with-radeon-vega-graphics-%C3%97-8) ([panariga](https://askubuntu.com/users/1083039/panariga)'s "Workaround 2") with which I could keep the IOMMU enabled in the BIOS and without needing any custom drivers. I get a steady 60 fps running glxgears.

> #### Workaround 2:
>
> Add `iommu=pt` to kernel command line in `/etc/default/grub`:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> Edit the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to look like this
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=pt"
> ```
>
> Update GRUB:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> Reboot
>
> ```
> reboot
> ```

This is on a Gigabyte B450M DS3H motherboard; running Linux Mint 19.3; kernel 5.3.0-53-generic (Ubuntu 18.04.1 -based); screen at 1920x1200 resolution.