# Artifacts with AMD® Ryzen 5 3400g with radeon vega graphics × 8

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, visual-artifacts, integrated

I have recently installed four computers with Linux. Each one has different monitors, refresh rates, versions, etc. The only constant in all four is the processor with the integrated graphics. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY4E1.jpg) is a screenshot that I was able to take.

[image: Here]

AMD doesn't have official drivers for Linux for this particular processor and I'm not entirely sure about where to go from here. Has anybody else had issues with this?

I have been conducting tests, and I see there is no issue at all with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04.3. I still have a little more testing to do, but I reckon it will start giving me issues as soon as I update my drivers in 18.04.

It turns out I was exactly right. It seems like there are issues with the current kernel with this specific AMD processor. We just ordered a few Nvidia graphics cards because we need to run programs that require specific kernels and we can't afford to waste any more time on this issue. If anybody needs a quick fix and doesn't necessarily care about which kernel version they are using, I found that version 5.0.0-23 works without any issues.

Comment: I can confirm that older kernels 5.0.0-23 work

Comment: I built a computer using the Ryzen 3, 3200G in may 2020, and had these problems too. However, only for a short period. Then, working drivers were included in the kernel when Kubuntu was updated and since then no problems whatsoever. Installed Ubuntu 22.04 (Beta) on the 2nd of april 2022, and everything is still just perfect.

Answer (score 8):

Same problems with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS / Ryzen 3 3200G / Gigabyte B450M S2H /
16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 3200

#### Workaround 1:

Disable IOMMU in BIOS

#### Workaround 2:

Add `iommu=pt` to kernel command line in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Edit the line beginging `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to look like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=pt"
```

Update GRUB:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot

```
reboot
```

Comment: What is iommu? And why does it work?

Comment: Yeah, is there a thread somewhere in the Ubuntu known errors targeting this. I would like to understand the core issue at play. Today I helped a friend get his system up and running (3400G in a GIGABYTE B450 H) and the only references I've found to this issue is this thread and another with the same symptoms. Is it just an issue with the Kernel shipped with 20.04 ?

Comment: Sure, iommu + AMD vega is broken completely and nobody today is working on fixing it in kernel. AMD just ignores this issue and don't want to spend developers time. If you want to have stable machine - use Intel + GMA + open source drivers.