# Annoying stripes in the frame update (AMD Ryzen 3200g APU)

Tags: amd-ryzen

I have a graphics problem and I don't know why, someone told me that Ubuntu does not have support for vega 8 graphics, and my PC has a 3200g Ryzen APU.

Frequently when changing frames (updating on a page or changing programs), horizontal stripes appear with parts of frames before the update, on other occasions they are black or white. This does not occur when I dual-boot into Windows.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Please also include the output of `uname -r` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208271/artifacts-with-amd-ryzen-5-3400g-with-radeon-vega-graphics-%C3%97-8) ([panariga](https://askubuntu.com/users/1083039/panariga)'s "Workaround 2") with which I could keep the IOMMU enabled in the BIOS and without needing any custom drivers.

> #### Workaround 2:
>
> Add `iommu=pt` to kernel command line in `/etc/default/grub`:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> Edit the line beginging `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to look like this
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=pt"
> ```
>
> Update GRUB:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> Reboot
>
> ```
> reboot
> ```