# Kubuntu 20.04 unstable display using AMD integrated Vega Graphics with kernel 5.4

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, amd-graphics, 20.04, amd-processor

After upgrading from *Kubuntu 18.04* to *20.04* (with *kernel 5.4.0-28-generic*) on my *AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics*. I started to experience problems with my display:

On the plus side, the desktop effects feels smoother, however my display blanks out from time to time, as well as leaving some artifacts after interactions with some plasmoids.

This seems to go away when I boot to the old kernel *4.15.0-99-generic* from the installation of *18.04*.

So my questions are:

1. **Are there known issues with the *Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics* with *Kernel 5.4.0-28-generic* as shipped by *Ubuntu 20.04* and *kwin 5.18.4*?**
2. **Are there any settings to *kwin* to make it more stable, even at the cost of losing some desktop effects?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not the kernel itself but the boot parameters passed to that kernel.

So the solution that worked for me was:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add [`nomodeset`](https://askubuntu.com/a/207177)) to the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="..."` line, as shown by this diff:

   ```
   --- a/etc/default/grub
   +++ b/etc/default/grub
   @@ -7,7 +7,7 @@
    GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
    GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
    GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
   -GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   +GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

    # Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
   ```
2. Generate the grub configuration for its templates:

   ```
    sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Reboot.

---

**Update:**

After adding `nomodeset` I noticed that:

- I am unable to use multiple monitors as noted by [this Linux mint forum thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=292348) and [this Linux-questions thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/dual-monitors-not-working-4175662087/)
- Some desktop effects are not working.

However the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1240565) suggested below by [Andrew Richards](https://askubuntu.com/users/1077410) did not work for me.

Comment: (moderator: Please convert this answer into a comment, not enough reputation to do so) This solution didn't work for me, but please see [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208271/artifacts-with-amd-ryzen-5-3400g-with-radeon-vega-graphics-%C3%97-8) which did (same steps, but different settings for the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line.