# Rendering issues after hardware upgrade

Tags: drivers, xorg, wayland, amd-ryzen

I upgraded my PC from i3 6100 to Ryzen3 3200g. Only on Ubuntu, these issue happen, not in Windows 10. On Firefox, Chromium, wine windows, Clion and other programs.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

These issues appear on screenshots too:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Seems a graphic card driver issue. I would try `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` or in Software & Updates > Aditional Drivers. The output of `inxi -SMG -! 31 -y 80` might be useful.

Comment: @PabloBianchi ´sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall´ does installs nothing, and the inxi command has a typo .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208271/artifacts-with-amd-ryzen-5-3400g-with-radeon-vega-graphics-%C3%97-8) the issues are because of the IOMMU, do:

> I found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208271/artifacts-with-amd-ryzen-5-3400g-with-radeon-vega-graphics-%C3%97-8)
> ([panariga](https://askubuntu.com/users/1083039/panariga)'s
> "Workaround 2") with which I could keep the IOMMU enabled in the BIOS
> and without needing any custom drivers. I get a steady 60 fps running
> glxgears.
>
> > #### Workaround 2:
> >
> > Add `iommu=pt` to kernel command line in `/etc/default/grub`:
> >
> > ```
> > sudo nano /etc/default/grub
> > ```
> >
> > Edit the line beginging `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to look like this
> >
> > ```
> > GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=pt"
> > ```
> >
> > Update GRUB:
> >
> > ```
> > sudo update-grub
> > ```
> >
> > Reboot
> >
> > ```
> > reboot
> > ```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Posts about LM are off topic here, as it isn't Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: LM? Whats that? This is about ubuntu 20.04 failing to render correctly. This fixes that, note that the idea was from another poster, but it worked for me, so I wanted to give attribution.

Comment: It is Linux Mint, the distro you use according to our own statement. :~)

Comment: The quotation ("This is on a Gigabyte B450M DS3H motherboard; running Linux Mint 19.3; kernel 5.3.0-53-generic (Ubuntu 18.04.1 -based); screen at 1920x1200 resolution.") is not mine, it's from another user. Copied it verbatim.

Comment: I see, looks like I need to retract the downvotes.